# Why the tabs of sherlock action bar are with different colors?

Tags: colors, tabs, actionbarsherlock

This happen in some android devices with a smallest display.

When the display is big my tabs stay inside of sherlock action bar.

In my style, everything is blue, i haven't any idea about this black on the selected tab and dividers.

See a print with my problem: http://www.fileupyours.com/files/321626/outro%20problema.png

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. The problem was in one parents `.Solid.Inverse`, i removed and `strange black color` disappeared.

Before:

```
parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse"
```

After:

```
parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar"
```